# Subscribe: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to just request an api url, and I dont need to care about the response.
The response is a content type text/html, that contain a text.
This is my code:

```
// import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
//import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';


 headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/html');
 const options: any = {headers: headers};
 this.http.get(this.ApiUrl, options)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {});
  }
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (localhost:80)

How to stop subscribe doing that `JSON.parse()` function In case of not having a json format as a response ??
Another question is there a way to catch exception ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: That's HttpClient and not RxJS

Comment: Maybe you need to provide correct mime-type with your request options... Which type is send from server and wich options do you provide?

Comment: Just update the question !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the response type as text, this can be done with a header - responseType: 'text':

```
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/html');
 headers.append('responseType', 'text');
 const options: any = {headers: headers};
 this.http.get(this.ApiUrl,  options)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {});
  }
```